# Docker: how to sync date between a CentOs host and a Debian container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, timezone

I have a CentOs host running a docker Debian container.

The container has the wrong localtime and timezone: how can I synchronize it with the host date?

I'm trying with mounting volumes on the docker-compose with /etc/localtime but it doesn't work.

The solution I prefer should be one of them:

- set a particular ENV in the Dockerfile
- mount properly volumes in the docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 2):

You can add your local file `/etc/localtime` as volume in your docker-container.
Update your docker-compose.yml with the following lines.

```
volumes:
    - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
```

And, Then:

```
# docker-compose up -d
```

Now the container time is the same as on your host.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

In the Dockerfile, write:

```
ENV TZ=<your timezone>
```

Example:

```
ENV TZ=Europe/Rome
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoudl define has an ENV the TZ and also add change the localtime softlink and place it in the timezone file:

```
ENV TZ=Europe/Lisbon
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```